# Implement validation using ajax along with php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am building a website using php+mysql. I have a registration page and its already implemented in php. Now i would like to make the page more dynamic and interactive using ajax.That is i would like to have a feature in which when user moves to next tab it should display message in previous field saying right/wrong depending on user entered data. Can anyone let me know is it possible to add this feature to already php page or should i start from scratch. Please let me know if any good sources for learning ajax

Comment: +1.  Also, the question itself seems a bit confused.  AJAX is only necessary when you want the page as loaded on the client machine to communicate back to the server.  If the validation is something that could be done by Javascript you can just write Javascript to be executed in the client's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp to learn about Ajax, or you could jump directly to [Ajax on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). A very important thing is to remember that even if you validate the fields using Ajax, you should always verify and [sanitize the input](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+sanitize+input) on the server when the form is processed, because web requests *can* be easily faked.